# SQL Query to calculates 'reserved' inventory items

Tags: mysql, sql, inventory, dbexpress, sqlfiddle

We are creating a inventory system for items called readoutprobes and readoutprobekits. The schema, below, is simplified, using the words *items* and *itemkits*.

[image]

An itemkit, is a predefined collection of 1 or more items, i.e. a kit. In a kit, a specific type of an item, can only occur once. A kit, typically contains ~40 items. The definition of items in a kit, is captured by the *itemkit_item* table. The inventory for the kits, are captured in the *itemkit_containers* table.

An itemkit_container *do not* track physical item containers. Instead, its assumed that a physical itemkit is properly 'assembled', using a set of physical items, but we don't know which ones. When populated, the 'populated' field in an itemkit_containers record, is set to true.

The inventory for *items* are tracked by a *item_containers* table. Its existence is monitored by the containers volume. When the volume is 0, the container is considered emptied.

Getting the count of physical item containers, with a volume > 0, for a specific item, is obtained from the item_container table, and the same for the kits

We want to get a *'reserved count'* number for each item, reflecting the kits inventory.

For example, say we got an item, named A, having a count of 42. If we are creating an itemkit containing an item named A, and a corresponding itemkit_container, we want to have a count of 'reserved' being 1, for item A.

The 'master query' for items looks like this:

```
SELECT items.*,         
    ic.item_count
FROM items
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT p.id, COUNT(*) item_count, ic.item_id
    FROM  items AS p, item_containers AS ic
    WHERE p.id = ic.item_id AND ic.volume > 0
    GROUP BY p.id
    ) AS ic   
    ON ic.item_id = items.id        
GROUP BY items.id    
ORDER BY items.id;
```

Data in the items table:

[image]

Data in the item_containers table:

[image]

Data in the itemkits table:

[image]

Data in the itemkit_item table:

[image]

And data in the itemkit_containers:

[image]

As can be observed, the only record of an itemkit, and its inventory, contains items with item ID's = {1,3}

This question is to find out how to query for the number of 'free' (or reserved) **physical items**, i.e. item_containers inventory there is, at any one point in time.

The above query, returns this result:

[image]

We want an additional field, that indicate a 'Reserved' count for each item, reflecting the status of actual inventory for items and itemkits.

For the data above, this would be

```
A -> Reserved = 1
B -> Reserved = 0
C -> Reserved = 1
D -> Reserved = 0
```

A db fiddle that creates and populates the above tables is here:
[DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0a07407642430e53be4040a568236a31)

We are using MySQL 8.0.

NOTE: The answer below is close to correct. However, it does not relate item_containers (actual invnetory) with the itemkit_container records, but instead the itemkit records. This become clear by toggling the populated field in the itemkit_containers table to '0'.  I.e.:

[image]

The output, even though the kit is no longer populated shows the same 'Reserved' count. Reserved should be equal to '0' in this case.
Here is a fiddle for that case: [Fiddle where Reserved should be all '0'](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=317a70e204252e633986cd672a696f30)

Comment: Provide CREATE TABLE for all tables, some sample data as INSERT INTO and desired result.

Comment: @Akina I updated the question with tables and data. I also simplified the wording. SQL to create and populate the tables is part of the question as well.

Comment: Please mention which version of mysql you are using.

Comment: I don't understand the "populated" column. If item 1 has three containers with volumes 0, 10, 15, then it has 25 pieces in stock. If item 1 is part of kit 10, kit 20, and kit 30  where kit 10 and 20 are populated and kit 30 is not, then how many pieces of item 1 are reserved, how many are free?

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner. Good question. Any item container with a volume > 0 is 'valid' and can be part of a kit. An item container with a volume > 0 is counted as '1', regardless of its volume.
The populated flag, found in the kit_containers table, indicate that a kit is 'populated', with relevant item containers. However, a populated kit don't reveal which item container was used, only its type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for such detailed description and all the necessary sample data.

As you already tried in your query you can have the item with quantity by joining items and item_containers table. For calculating free or reserved item you need to left join itemkit_containsers table since inventory for items in a kit is stored there. So just calculate the count for any item in itemkit_containers then you got your reserved quantity and by subtracting it from item_count of item_containsers table will give you free quantity for that item.

Schema and insert statements:

```
 CREATE TABLE `items` (
   `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `name` varchar(512) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'oligoname + fluorophore wavelength',
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1006 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci COMMENT='ReadoutProbes for mFISH Survey';
 
 CREATE TABLE `item_containers` (
   `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `item_id` int NOT NULL COMMENT 'content of tube',
   `volume` float(12,2) NOT NULL COMMENT 'volume in micro liter (uL)',
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   KEY `fk_item_containers_items` (`item_id`),
   CONSTRAINT `fk_item_containers_items` FOREIGN KEY (`item_id`) REFERENCES `items` (`id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=764 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci COMMENT='Physical tubes received from vendor';
 
 CREATE TABLE `itemkits` (
   `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`),
   UNIQUE KEY `Unique` (`name`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1030 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci COMMENT='A readout kit is a collection of readouts, and defined in a codebook';
 
 CREATE TABLE `itemkit_containers` (
   `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `itemkit_id` int NOT NULL,
   `populated` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Field used for checking in checking out a tray',
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   KEY `fk_readoutkit_tray_readoutkits` (`itemkit_id`),
   CONSTRAINT `fk_readoutkit_tray_readoutkits` FOREIGN KEY (`itemkit_id`) REFERENCES `itemkits` (`id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1027 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci COMMENT='Physical readoutkit_tray';
 
 CREATE TABLE `itemkit_item` (
   `itemkit_id` int NOT NULL,
   `item_id` int NOT NULL,
   UNIQUE KEY `Uniqueness` (`itemkit_id`,`item_id`),
   KEY `fk_readoutkit_item_readout_probes` (`item_id`),
   CONSTRAINT `fk_readoutkit_item_readout_probes` FOREIGN KEY (`item_id`) REFERENCES `items` (`id`),
   CONSTRAINT `fk_readoutkit_item_readoutkits` FOREIGN KEY (`itemkit_id`) REFERENCES `itemkits` (`id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci COMMENT='associations table for definition of a readout kit';
       
 insert  into `items`(`id`,`name`) values 
 (1,'A'),
 (2,'B'),
 (3,'C'),
 (4,'D');
 
 insert  into `itemkits`(`id`,`name`) values 
 (1,'Kit_1');
 
 insert  into `itemkit_containers`(`itemkit_id`,`populated`) values 
 (1,0);
 
 insert  into `itemkit_item`(`itemkit_id`,`item_id`) values 
 (1,1),
 (1,3);
 
 insert  into `item_containers`(`item_id`,`volume`) values 
 (1,1.00),
 (2,1.00),
 (3,1.00),
 (4,1.00),
 (1,1.00);
```

Query:

```
select i.id,i.name,sum(ic.volume) as total_volume,
      sum(coalesce(ii.item_count,0)) as Reserved 
      from items i inner join item_containers ic on i.id=ic.item_id
      left join (select item_id,count(*) as item_count from itemkit_containers ic
      inner join itemkit_item i on ic.itemkit_id =i.itemkit_id and ic.populated=1
      group by item_id) ii
      on i.id=ii.item_id
      group by i.id,i.name
      order by i.id,i.name
```

Output:

| id | name | total_volume | Reserved |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 2.00 | 0 |
| 2 | B | 1.00 | 0 |
| 3 | C | 1.00 | 0 |
| 4 | D | 1.00 | 0 |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6b8c6d665b44a1be77282448465a1cda)*

Db-Fiddle with with populated and not populated itemkit_containsers:

Select queries (sample data):

```
 SELECT * from items;
 SELECT item_id, volume from item_containers;
 SELECT * FROM itemkits;
 SELECT itemkit_id, populated FROM itemkit_containers;
 SELECT * FROM itemkit_item;
```

Output:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | C |
| 4 | D |

| item_id | volume |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1.00 |
| 2 | 1.00 |
| 3 | 1.00 |
| 4 | 1.00 |
| 1 | 1.00 |

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Kit_1 |
| 2 | Kit_2 |

| itemkit_id | populated |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 |

| itemkit_id | item_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |

Query:

```
      select i.id,i.name,sum(ic.volume) as total_volume,
      sum(coalesce(ii.item_count,0)) as Reserved 
      from items i inner join item_containers ic on i.id=ic.item_id
      left join (select item_id,count(*) as item_count from itemkit_containers ic
      inner join itemkit_item i on ic.itemkit_id =i.itemkit_id and ic.populated=1
      group by item_id) ii
      on i.id=ii.item_id
      group by i.id,i.name
      order by i.id,i.name
```

Output:

| id | name | total_volume | Reserved |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 2.00 | 0 |
| 2 | B | 1.00 | 1 |
| 3 | C | 1.00 | 0 |
| 4 | D | 1.00 | 0 |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=00afb870d08d704b03af62a24e7805a5)*

Comment: Please have a look into this answer and let me know if I have missed anything

Comment: Got delayed in my response. This is kind of the answer on the question, however I think my question and input data is missing an important point. I will update the question and make a fiddle with some updated data. Certainly will award the bounty nonetheless!

Comment: I updated the question to be clearer. The problem is that the answer related itemcontainers with itemkits, and not itemkit_containers. 
I removed the concept of 'Free' from the question, as 'Reserved' is the main question here.

Comment: @TotteKarlsson Thanks for the fiddle. I have changed my answer. Please have a look.

Comment: @TotteKarlsson I have also created a fiddle where I have created two itemkit one with populated status 1 and other with 0 in itemkit_containsers. Please check the query and output. Hope it's what you are looking for. That many left join is not necessary I think. Please let me know if I missed anything.

Comment: Thanks @TotteKarlsson for accepting my answer. Best wishes.

Answer (score 1):

Added the sql statement which considers `populated column of itemkit_containers` and gives correct output for `reserved counts`.

**Query:**

```
SELECT items.*,         
    ic.*,
    v.total_volume,
    COALESCE(item_in_kit.item_count,0) AS Reserved
FROM items
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT i.id, COUNT(*) item_count, ic.item_id
    FROM  items AS i, item_containers AS ic
    WHERE i.id = ic.item_id AND ic.volume > 0
    GROUP BY i.id
    ) AS ic   
    ON ic.item_id = items.id        
    
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT items.id, COALESCE(SUM(ic.volume),0) total_volume
    FROM items, item_containers AS ic
    WHERE items.id = ic.item_id
    GROUP BY items.id
    ) AS v
    ON items.id = v.id
    
LEFT JOIN item_containers 
    ON item_containers.item_id = items.id
    
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT item_id, COUNT(*) AS item_count 
    FROM itemkit_item where itemkit_id not in
    (select itemkit_id from itemkit_containers where populated = 0)
    GROUP BY item_id
    ) item_in_kit
    ON items.id = item_in_kit.item_id        
    
GROUP BY items.id    
ORDER BY items.id;
```

**Output:**

| id | name | id | item_count | item_id | total_volume | Reserved |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1 | 2 | 1 | 2.00 | 0 |
| 2 | B | 2 | 1 | 2 | 1.00 | 0 |
| 3 | C | 3 | 1 | 3 | 1.00 | 0 |
| 4 | D | 4 | 1 | 4 | 1.00 | 0 |

[Fiddle with correct reserved](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b5103eae615f3a48b365969fb001f1e0)

Answer (score 1):

First compute totals and reserved from the appropriate containers then left join totals and reserved to items.

```
SELECT items.id, items.name,
    coalesce(total.v, 0) AS Total_volume,
    coalesce(rsvd.v, 0) AS Reserved
FROM items
LEFT JOIN ( /* item total in item_containers  */
       SELECT item_id, SUM(volume) v
       FROM item_containers 
       GROUP BY item_id
    ) AS total ON items.id = total.item_id
LEFT JOIN( /* item reservation by itemkit_containers  */
       SELECT iki.item_id, count(*) v
       FROM itemkit_containers AS ic
       JOIN itemkit_item AS iki
       ON ic.itemkit_id = iki.itemkit_id AND ic.Populated = 1
       GROUP BY iki.item_id 
    ) AS rsvd ON items.id = rsvd.item_id
ORDER BY items.id;
```

[db-fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=630ef0728ccda99087b39ef8f6fe3df5)

Comment: This looks a little shorter than the answer I awarded.